# Android: CustomListAdapter columns not aligning properly

Tags: android, xml, listadapter

I have a page that displays a list of items. Each row in the list has three columns and for some reason, the items int he list are not aligning properly.
Below is my code:

Custom Adapter:

```
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvCategoryName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Name"
    android:layout_weight="0.90"
    android:textAlignment="textStart"/>

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvWeight"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Weight"
    android:layout_weight="0.05"
    android:textAlignment="center"/>

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvAverage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Average"
    android:layout_weight="0.05"
    android:textAlignment="center"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Below is a screenshot of how it gets displayed:
[image]

I want `Categories`, `Weight`, and `Average` all three columns to be displayed in a nice table like format with `centered` text-alignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATED: Set `layout_width="0dp"` to all yours TextViews. Otherwise the layout_weight will not work properly. For vertical oriented parent layout set `layout_height="0"`

And maybe the `android:layout_weight="0.05"` is too little, try to use some bigger value, like 0.2 for tvWeight and tvAverage and 0.6 for tvCategoryName.

Comment: That still doesn't work when the "category names" are too long or too short

Comment: Yes, if you are using layout_weight, you should set layout_width to 0dp